# Is creating 2 honeypots better than 1?

Tags: php, forms, validation, honeypot

To avoid automatic form submission from a bot I have been looking into the honeypot solution.

I was thinking, from a hackers point-of-view, that I would create a script that (if failed to submit) would alternate leave form fields blank until the form was submitted.

This leads me to think that it might be a good idea to have at least 2 honeypot fields in the form. Or perhaps their position gets rearranged after the form is attempted submission.

Would it make sense to have multiple honeypots? Or is there some technique out there to avoid obvious hacker workarounds like the one I suggested above?

Comment: doesn't `captcha` help?

Comment: captcha helps some people. we are looking to minimize user effort during the sign in process. captcha has a look that we don't like and we think it frustrates most end-users.